# Don't understand the error message : Invalid syntax in for statement

Tags: python, for-loop, numbers, syntax-error, equals

I am writing a very simple program to output the 0-10 in numbers using a for loop. However it comes up with a syntax error when I click run, highlighting in red the "=" in the 8th line. I don't understand why it is wrong? I am using python 3.5.2 in idle mode.

```
def numbers():
    print ("This program will count to ten, just you wait...")
    import time
    time.sleep(1)
    print ("\n\nLiterally wait I just need to remember base 10 because I 
    only work in binary!")
    time.sleep(4)
    int(counter) = 0
    for counter <**=** 9: 
    print ("\n" + counter)
    counter =  counter + 1

    print ("\n\nAnd there you go. Told you I could do it. Goodbye :) ")
    time.sleep(2)
    exit()

numbers()
```

Comment: Your `for` statement is invalid. You're looking for `while`, or the [Python docs](http://python.org).

Comment: What is your intention with `int(counter) = 0`? This is not valid python syntax. It should read `counter = 0`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try it like this:

```
def numbers():
    print ("This program will count to ten, just you wait...")
    import time
    time.sleep(1)
    print ("\n\nLiterally wait I just need to remember base 10 because I only work in binary!")
    time.sleep(4)
    for i in range(1, 10): #11 if you want 10 to be printed
        print i

    print ("\n\nAnd there you go. Told you I could do it. Goodbye :) ")
    time.sleep(2)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is wrong syntax for `for`. As per [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#for):

> The for statement is used to iterate over the elements of a sequence (such as a string, tuple or list) or other iterable object.

which is not your case, or you can use `range()` to create the sequence:

```
for i in range(1, 10):
```

yet it's artificial workaround and while it will work, is not what you should be doing really.

You should use `while` instead. [Docs](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#while) say:

> The while statement is used for repeated execution as long as an expression is true

```
while counter <= 9:
```

Answer (score 0):

A couple of points. The excerpt:

```
int(counter) = 0
for counter <**=** 9: 
print ("\n" + counter)
counter =  counter + 1
```

has multiple errors.

1. `int(counter) = 0` is not valid python syntax.
2. `for counter <**=** 9` is not a valid `for` statement.
3. The lines `print ("\n" + counter)` and `counter =  counter + 1` are lacking proper indentation.

Replace those four lines with

```
for counter in range(10):
    print(counter)
```